# How to deal with HTML select using in a scotty and Text.Blaze.Html5

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, scotty

I am using [scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) and

- [`Text.Blaze.Html5`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html-0.9.1.2/docs/Text-Blaze-Html5.html)
- [`Text.Digestive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors-0.8.4.0/docs/Text-Digestive.html)
- [`Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors-blaze-0.6.2.0/docs/Text-Digestive-Blaze-Html5.html)

  What I want to achieve is a list of options as shown below.

[Option select example image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HY0CUmol2TbY7Le8DVyDppo0Hg8Im1Km)

I have a `Option` sum type and will like to restrict the user to those options.

```hs
data Options = Option1 | Option2 | Option3 | Option4 deriving Show
```

My problem is with [`Text.Digestive.choice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors-0.8.4.0/docs/Text-Digestive-Form.html#v:choice) 
I don't know how to use it and will appreciate your help on the correct way to achieve this.

I have tried to use the code below but battle to get it right.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import ClassyPrelude
import Web.Scotty.Trans
import Domain.Auth.Types
import Text.Digestive.Scotty
import qualified Text.Digestive.Form as DF
import qualified Text.Digestive.View as DF
import Text.Digestive.Form ((.:))
import Adapter.HTTP.Common
import Adapter.HTTP.Web.Common
import Katip
import Text.Blaze.Html5 ((!))
import qualified Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5 as DH
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as A
import qualified Data.Text as T 

registerForm :: Monad m => Form Text m Register
registerForm = Register
   <$> "name"     .: text Nothing  
   <*> "options" .: choice options Nothing
   where
     options= [(Option1, "Option1"),(Option2, "Option2"),  (Option3,
      "Option3"),(Option4, "Option4")]
registerView:: View H.Html -> H.Html
registerView view = do
    label     "name" view "Name: "
    inputText "name" view
    H.br
    
    label       "options" view "Options: "
    inputSelect "options" view
    H.br
```

I get the following error when I compile the code .

```
[14 of 23] Compiling Adapter.HTTP.Web.Auth ( src/Adapter/HTTP/Web/Auth.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Adapter/HTTP/Web/Auth.o )

/root/work/src/Adapter/HTTP/Web/Auth.hs:107:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Char’
        arising from the literal ‘"Option1"’
    • In the first argument of ‘pack’, namely ‘"Option1"’
      In the expression: pack "Option1"
      In the expression: (Option1, pack "Option1")
    |
107 |     options=  [(Option1,pack "Option1"),(Option2,pack "Option2"),(Option3,pack "Option3"),(Option4,pack "Option4")] 
    |                             ^^^^^

/root/work/src/Adapter/HTTP/Web/Auth.hs:129:7: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Text -> DF.View H.Html -> H.Html)
                                    -> [Char]
                                    -> DF.View [Text]
                                    -> [Char]
                                    -> DF.View [Text]
                                    -> (H.Html -> H.Html)
                                    -> H.Html
                                    -> H.Html’
                  with actual type ‘blaze-markup-0.8.0.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
                                      ()’
    • The function ‘H.label’ is applied to 7 arguments,
      but its type ‘H.Html
                    -> blaze-markup-0.8.0.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()’
      has only one
      In the expression:
        H.label
          "Options" DH.inputSelect "package.category" view "group" view H.div
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘H.label
           "Options" DH.inputSelect "package.category" view "group" view H.div
           $ errorList' "option"’
    |
129 |       H.label "Options"

No tix files found in /root/work/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-10.3/8.2.2/hpc/, so not generating a unified coverage report.

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package hauth-0.1.0.0 using:
      /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build lib:hauth exe:hauth-exe test:hauth-test --ghc-options "-hpcdir .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/hpc -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't need to `pack` a `String` literal if you have `OverloadedStrings` enabled. Could you please trim down your example to make it more minimal - for example, the `name` and `email` form fields don't seem relevant to the question?